# C++: STL map, inserting new value doesn't work

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to create a map using STL C++. But I am getting into problems and am not able to figure out whats exactly is wrong.

For demonstration purposes I put down my code here.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;

struct COORD{

    int X;
    int Y;

    bool operator<(const COORD &other) const { return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;}

    COORD(int x, int y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
 };

struct CAR{

    double speed;
    double model;
    double direc;
    CAR() {}
    CAR(double c1, double c2, double c3) {
            speed = c1;
            model = c2;
            direc = c3;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    map <COORD, CAR> p;
    p.insert(pair<COORD, CAR>(COORD(20, 20), CAR(10.0, 10.0, 10.0)));
    p.insert(pair<COORD, CAR>(COORD(20, 30), CAR(20.0, 10.0, 10.0)));

    CAR c1 = p.at(COORD(20, 30));
    cout << c1.speed << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So when you execute the code, the new inserted value is not displayed. Actually if you try to update the old one that also doesn't work. Can anyone let me know whats wrong. Why this is happening?

Comment: Your `operator <` looks somewhat suspect (you've implemented an operator == by the looks of it)

Comment: You probably should not use class names like _ _ CAR _ _ for your classes. Double-underscore identifiers are reserved.

Comment: Plus they are horrible to read and type.  Here's a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: I would recommend using std::make_pair when inserting pairs in to a map

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your less-than comparison **must** implement a [*strict weak ordering*](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). This is a requirement, without which, the maps cannot work. Your less-than operator does not respect that.

This is an example of a comparison that would work:

```
#include <tuple> // for std::tie

bool operator<(const COORD &other) const 
{
  return std::tie(X, Y) < std::tie(other.X, other.Y);
}
```

where the `std::tie` comparison is lexicographical, using `X` first, then `Y`. I also changed the name of the class to `COORD` because `__COORD__` is a reserved name.

Comment: The answer is just perfect. And thanks everyone for pointing out the correct method for writing identifiers.

Comment: Just one more question. If i insert a new CAR at the same key. It doesn't update it. What could be the fault?

Comment: @Psypher That is by design, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). If you want to over-write a value with an existing key, or insert a new element if one isn't present, use `operator[]`, i.e. `p[SomeKey] = SomeValue;`.

Comment: but as you know the structure is complex type therefore I cannot really use it in `operator[]`. How can this be then accomplished. In your opinion am I approaching the problem in a hard way or there can be a simple (other method) all i want is to create a look up table so later I can use 'USER' and assign them a car based on `USER` coordinate i.e. based on `USER` coordinate look for the near by car and assign it to him

Comment: @Psypher of course you can use it in `operator[]`, that is how maps work. I don't follow your user-coordinate thing, but it sounds like a different question.

Comment: Yes you indeed correct. I found my mistake. I didn't use a default contructor in my CAR structure and therefore the compiler was complaining about not finding the right object.